# Solution needed to Limit Server to only IP

Tags: networking, ip, linux-networking, ipsec

I want to limit my Dev server to only me. I am using a non static IP at home, I don't know if it's a A B or C type, if this matters -- I could go with a C type if it's the case for a firewall.

Besides that I gave to look into I have a few questions, I'm just asking for advice on any of them.

- A VPS with Elastic IP for a static IP, is this a good way to do this? It'd cost $9/mo on DO, perhaps cheaper with reserved AWS micro and elastic IP.
- Dedicated IP via SaaS are expensive, I can do this myself for less I believe.
- Why is a dedicated/static IP so much $? I don't want it through my ISP.
- The possibility of Tunneling via DNS w/VPN? (if domain servers change IP wouldn't matter, perhaps resolv.conf can figure this out?).
- Other way to identify a server knows it's me?

I'm doing this from home and wonder how people go about this in an affordable way.

Please suggest a solution. Comment is good also, but I'll mark the best suggestion as the answer!

Thanks!

Comment: When you said "VPN" did you actually mean "VPS"?

Comment: Oops I meant VPS, fixing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, lemme get this out of the way:

> I don't know if it's a A B or C type, if this matters -- I could go
>   with a C type if it's the case for a firewall.

Classful addressing has not been a thing for 20 years. Using that terminology now is a sure way to get yourself marked as someone who "doesn't know what they're talking about". Look into [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing). That is the modern term to use when discussing subnets.

With that taken care of, I'll take each of your bullets in turn:

> A VPN with Elastic IP for a static IP, is this a good way to do this?
>   It'd cost $9/mo on DO, perhaps cheaper with reserved AWS micro and
>   elastic IP.

I dunno, what are your requirements? If all you want is a simple server, then DO is the way to go. If you'll need to expand into more complex infrastructure at some point, then go with AWS. Using AWS has another benefit which I'll address below.

> Dedicated IP via SaaS are expensive, I can do this myself for less I
>   believe.

OK, if you say so.

> Why is a dedicated/static IP so much $? I don't want it through my
>   ISP.

It's more expensive because 1) it's something your ISP now has to manage and 2) IPv4 addresses are a finite resource and getting a static IP means that you and only you are consuming that resource.

> The possibility of Tunneling via DNS VPN (if domain servers change IP
>   wouldn't matter, perhaps resolv.conf can figure this out?).

I have no idea what you mean by this, but I'm fairly certain it's not relevant to your goals.

> Other way to identify a server knows it's me?

Well two options come to mind:

1. Use AWS, which will let you put a security group in front of your EC2 instance. The firewall rules on this security group can be modified programmatically using the AWS cli, meaning that you could run a command periodically from your home to update the security group to accept traffic from your current IP. You could do something approximating this with DO - they have no network-level firewall like AWS does, but you could connect to your server using their remote web console and adjust firewall rules when your IP changes.
2. Use IPsec (or some other VPN) to connect to your server. Only expose publicly the ports necessary for VPN functionality. All other ports would only be available after successful connection to the VPN. Implement two-factor auth (certificate + user/pass) and this would be quite secure.

Either of those options would give you a reasonably-secure, flexible environment to work in, without incurring a large amount of management overhead.

Comment: Thank you so much, for the greatly detailed answer! I'll have to stop calling IP's based on ABC! That #1 tip is amazing, wow. I am amazed at that idea! I am going to do more research on #2, this was incredibly informative. I've been trying to think through this a while, you've helped me think a lot differently, thank you!

Comment: I also found no-ip.com and you can use this to allocate your dynamic IP to a hostname (It runs as a service in the background Win/Linux/Mac), if you could VPN into a server with a hostname that's similar to what I was referring to with DNS via VPN, this fellow asks it well: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/77420/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-use-a-domain-name-to-access-my-vpn